# Save via VBA as xlsx and pdf simulteneously

Tags: excel, vba

My current vba programm lets the user select a path to save an excel file as a pdf. Now I also want to save that same file to the same path as an excel file. Somehow I cant get it to work.

Here´s my current code:

```
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                "PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Untersuchungsbericht speichern", _
                 InitialFileName:="Kunststoffsägen Untersuchungsbericht Auftragsnummer " & KunststoffsägenDE2.TextBoxAuftrag.Value)

ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords") = KunststoffsägenDE2.TextBoxAuftrag.Value & " " & KunststoffsägenDE2.TextBoxMaterial.Value & " " & KunststoffsägenDE2.TextBoxFortlaufend.Value & " Untersuchungsbericht" & " Kunststoffsägen" & " Laufleistung"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlTypePDF, OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True
```

Comment: I don't see in your code you setting your file filter to xls or xlsx / xlsm.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ....`?